# getAttribute is not available on the ElementHandle

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I'm using playwright version 0.13.0,

I have an instance of `ElementHandle`, but the `getAttribute` function is not available, calling it throws an error saying `getAttribute` is not a function:

```
await myElem.getAttribute('src')
```

I double-checked with the debugger, the function is not on the instance.

Also, there's no equivalent of `page.evaluate` function for `ElementHandle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass it as an argument to the `page.evaluate` function:

```js
await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('src'), myElem);
```

or

```js
await myElem.evaluate(node => node.getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: i personally think the following syntax is slightly nicer to read.  
`await myElem.evaluate(node => node.getAttribute('src');`

Answer (score 1):

For new comers to this, later versions of Playwright support the API used by OP. See: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#elementhandlegetattributename

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const attr = await page.$eval('.your-locator-class', el => el.src)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solved it using playwright native getter - .getAttribute('someAttribute');

For example you can write something like that:

const locator = await page.locator('[name="SomeLocator"]').getAttribute('content');